# mockMvc, get content from json file in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, mockmvc, wiremock

I have a springBoot 2.1.9.RELEASE application that uses MockMvc.

I would like to know if there is a way to get the content of the body from a file

```
mockMvc.perform(post("/hostel")
    .content(withBodyFile("hostel.json"))
```

like we can do with

```
com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.ResponseDefinitionBuilder (withBodyFile)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use something like:

```java
@SneakyThrows
private byte[] fromFile(String path) {
    return new ClassPathResource(path).getInputStream().readAllBytes();
}
```

And then:

```java
.content(fromFile("payload.json")))
```

Just bear in mind that the `payload.json` file must be under the `src/test/resources` folder.

Comment: Why isn't there any built-in way to do it? Is this so uncommon? It feels weird to me, looks like I'm doing something wrong

Answer (score 0):

`MockMvc`'s `content` can only be a `byte[]`. So, you can have your code read body from a file like

```
public byte[] bytesFromPath(final String path) throws IOException {

    return Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path));
}
```

```
.content(bytesFromPath(new ClassPathResource("file-name").getPath()));
```